# Automating testing for Multiple Sites

Tags: qtp

Apologies if this has been asked before, I've spent the last few days banging my head against QTP and Google and I'm getting nowhere with both.

I have a series of QTP scripts for several sites and I'd like to tie them all together into one master script.  My expectation was that I could simply call these external actions and QTP would go to the website associated with each one, do its testing, and then proceed to the next website and the next set of testing.  Instead QTP seems to be trying to run all of the actions on only one site.

I'm still a novice, so I assume it's something really basic and stupid that I'm missing.  What I'm attempting here seems pretty simple.  Any help or resources would be appreciated.

Comment: Yuo may get more responses if you can provide a bit more detail on how and where you are opening and identifying browsers, and what code you have for navigating to the different sites.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup an **Action Parameter** for the URL. If my understanding is correct, you have 1 Action for each website.

- Right click the **Action** and choose **Action Properties**.
- At the **Parameters** tab, add "strURL" and the intended URL for that action.

In your script, in the part where you're invoking the URL, use:

```
SystemUtil.Run Parameter("strURL")
```

Or modify it according to your script's existing logic in launching the URL.

Answer (score 0):

declare 2 browsers in your ObjectRepository FireFox/IE
and run your test at the same time in parallel on 2 sites